# jQuery UI dialog resize close button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm creating some dialog boxes using jQUery UI, but, the "close" button is too small in mobile devices. I need to resize only the close button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this simple solution, using CSS:

```
<style>
    .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { width: 30px !important; height: 24px !important; top: 40% !important }
</style>
```

This way affect all the dialog boxes, which is the desired effect.

Comment: TO avoid affecting this code to all other dialogs you should give your dialog `<div>` and `id` and give edit your `css`. And if you want the close button to appear bigger only on mobile devices thne you should make media css file that will load certain css codes when the screen resolution gets to a specified dimensions. By this way you would have a control on when to show bigger and smaller icon !

Comment: @RahulGupta my intended behavior was this, but your comment are valid. in my case, is ok to show a bigger close button on desktop computers  :)